# $watch not working inside Angular Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a $watch on a radio button inside [AngularJS Modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). However $watch is not working inside modal for any value changes.

If I try to put the radio buttons outside modal, the $watch works perfectly fine.

http://plnkr.co/edit/q8t9qGJg57MMiQGop202?p=preview

In the above plunkr, if you click on Open me and select upper 2 radio buttons (me, you) $watch is not fired and in turn u cant see the alert with the value.

However if you click on radio buttons in the main page (i.e. Outside window) $watch works perfectly fine and throws alert message.

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a symptom of violating the unofficial golden rule when using `ng-model`:

> Always have a "." in your ng-model expression

If you don't have a dot in your ng-model expression, it will create a property on the current scope at the point where the element with ng-model is. This will often not be the scope you are expecting, as many directives create child scopes, including the modal directive from UI Bootstrap.

By including a dot, you are referencing an object, which will be looked up on the prototype (scope) chain, and then accessing or creating a property on *that*, which will be on the correct scope.

Thus, in your example, if you change your code so that you create a `$scope.data` property in your controller, and set your `ng-model` expression to `data.rdd`, you will be able to "see" the changes in the controller and respond to them.

Thus the controller code function body starts with:

```
  $scope.data = {
    rdd: 'me'
  };

  $scope.$watch('data.rdd', function(v, old){
    if(v!==undefined && v !== old)
      alert(v);
  });
```

And your radio buttons in your HTML should be:

```
        <input type="radio" ng-model="data.rdd" value="me">me
        <input type="radio" ng-model="data.rdd" value="you">you
```

I [forked your Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9HfTXWDnDJ7oCUliirHY?p=preview) so it now works.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Worked like a Charm :)

Comment: The more I use other frameworks (reactJS, flightJS, ember) the more I hate Angular. It's make you really productive, until you find things like these......

Comment: So how do you get the parent doc to sync up with the data change? When you switch the radio in the modal, I'd expect to see the parent change as well.